# What is the right setting for the Appium directory in Katalon Studio on a Mac?

Tags: testing, mobile, automated-tests, appium, katalon-studio

Katalon Studio shows an error when starting the Mobile Recorder with having set the Appium directory to `/Applications/Appium.app` or `/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/MacOS`.

> Unable to start application on this device: : Appium directory is
>   invalid: Cannot find Appium executable file.

How do you fix this on a Mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install Appium from the command line instead of downloading the Mac app.

```
npm install -g appium
```

After that, set the *Appium Directory* in Katalon Studio to
`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium`

Answer (score 2):

Installing Appium from the command line via brew:

```
brew install appium
```

Then set in Katalon > Preferences > Mobile > Appium Directory:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/appium/1.21.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/appium
```

or something similar depended on version